# How to test asynchronous website activity between two users

Tags: testing, jasmine, bdd

We're trying to write BDD tests using Jasmine, and a common use case we need to handle is:

```
User A: Does some action
User B: Gets notified after xx ms that the action has happened asynchronously (either via WebPush or polling)
User B: Responds to user A's action
User A: Receives B's response
```

I'm struggling to build an automated test for this scenario.  Our current tool-of-choice is Jasmine, but we're flexible at this point.  How can you handle multiple logins simultaneously, especially where there is some delay between responses?

Answer (score 1):

The naive way to do it is to simply poll for each action, and move the scenario on once that action has been detected, with timeouts that fail the test if it takes too long.

In any language which allows for multi-threaded execution, you can create a "Waiter" pattern which waits for the event, then passes execution back to the test once that event has been detected. I've got [a C# example here](https://code.google.com/p/wipflash/source/browse/WiPFlash/Framework/Waiter.cs) and [a Java example here](https://code.google.com/p/tyburn/source/browse/trunk/src/java/org/lunivore/tyburn/threaded/QueuedMiniHashMap.java).

Javascript doesn't allow for multi-threaded execution, but [it can be faked](http://www.sitepoint.com/multi-threading-javascript/).

However, I think your biggest problem is that with two logins, you've essentially got two tabs or windows or tabs or apps, and yes, that's going to be hard to manage. You could do it with something that interacts with windows, rather than with the browser (my C# example is from an automation tool that does this), but that would mean adopting a whole different tech stack for the automated scenarios.

You can get around it though by dividing your scenario up into portions:

> Given users A and B are running the app
> When user A does some action
> Then user B should be notified.

For B, use a fake version of the app; stub out everything from the service onwards. You can then check that B is notified via the service's API. You could even just write the things that B receives to a text file, or something similar. It doesn't have to be a real B.

> Given users A and B are running the app
> When user B receives a notification from user A
> Then user B should respond.
>
> Given users A and B are running the app
> When user B responds
> Then user A should be notified.

For these ones, we're now stubbing out the app for A, notifying as A through the API in the first and verifying notification from B in the 2nd.

> Given user A is waiting for user B's response
> When A receives user B's response
> Then A should (do whatever they would normally do when they receive that response).

And we're back to stubbing out B again, injecting B's response into the API, bringing the journey full-circle.

In each case, we're still verifying that the interaction with the service works; we're just not doing it all at the same time. This should still provide enough confidence that everything is good. It just takes a few more scenarios to do it.

Please do talk to the business about this too and use the language that they use when describing what they do, rather than A and B notifications and responses like I have here.